# How to change background-color of navigation when redirecting from homepage to other pages using useLocation on Scroll in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

BELOW IS MY CODE : HEADER.JS
When I click on shop button in navigation on homepage -> http://localhost:3000/ then it should go to -> http://localhost:3000/product-listing and should add a bg-black class on nav tag and should stay black background.

IMPORTS---

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Loading from "../other/Loading";
import PageNotFound from "../other/PageNotFound";
import { NavLink, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const Header = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [headerData, setHeaderData] = useState(null);
  const [bgBlack, setBgBlack] = useState("");
  const [border, setBorder] = useState("");
  const [textColor, setTextColor] = useState("");

  const location = useLocation();
  console.log(location.pathname);
```

USE EFFECT---

```
useEffect(() => {
    getHeaderData();
    window.addEventListener("scroll", changeBackground);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", changeBackground);
    };
  }, []);
```

GET HEADER NAVIGATION DATA---

```
const getHeaderData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/navLinks");
      const data = await response.json();
      if (data) {
        setLoading(false);
        setHeaderData(data);
      } else {
        setHeaderData("DATA NOT FOUND");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("OOPS... SOMETHING WENT WRONG");
      }
    }
  };
```

CHANGE NAV BACKGROUND-COLOR---

```
const changeBackground = () => {
    if (window.scrollY > 5) {
      setBgBlack("bg-black");
      setBorder("border-bottom");
      setTextColor("text-white");
    } else {
      setBgBlack("");
      setBorder("");
      setTextColor("");
    }
  };
```

IF LOADING IS TRUE LOAD LOADING COMPONENT---

```
if (loading) {
    return (
      <>
        <Loading loadingHeader="Loading Header" />
      </>
    );
  }

  // console.log(headerData);
```

RETURN JSX---

```
return (
    <>
      {headerData ? (
        <header>
          <nav
            className={`navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light ${bgBlack} fixed-top`}
          >
            <div className="container">
              <div>
                <button
                  className="navbar-toggler"
                  type="button"
                  data-toggle="collapse"
                  data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                  aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                  aria-expanded="false"
                  aria-label="Toggle navigation"
                >
                  <span className="text-white">
                    <i className="fa fa-bars"></i>
                  </span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="order-lg-0">
                <NavLink className="navbar-brand" to="/">
                  <img
                    width="50"
                    src={headerData.logo.url}
                    className="img-fluid"
                    alt=""
                  />
                </NavLink>
              </div>
              <div className="order-lg-2 d-lg-none">
                <span
                  className="text-white d-flex"
                  data-toggle="modal"
                  data-target="#mobileCartModal"
                >
                  <span className="d-inline-block mr-1">
                    <i className="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                  </span>
                  <span className="d-inline-block">0</span>
                </span>
              </div>
              <div
                className="collapse navbar-collapse order-lg-1"
                id="navbarSupportedContent"
              >
                <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto px-3">
                  {/* <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a
                      className="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                      href="#"
                      id="navbarDropdown"
                      role="button"
                      data-toggle="dropdown"
                      aria-haspopup="true"
                      aria-expanded="false"
                    >
                      Packages
                    </a>
                    <div
                      className="dropdown-menu"
                      aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown"
                    >
                      <a className="dropdown-item" href="product.html">
                        Subscriptions
                      </a>
                      <a className="dropdown-item" href="product.html">
                        Value Packs
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a
                      className="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                      href="#"
                      id="navbarDropdown"
                      role="button"
                      data-toggle="dropdown"
                      aria-haspopup="true"
                      aria-expanded="false"
                    >
                      Juices
                    </a>
                    <div
                      className="dropdown-menu"
                      aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown"
                    >
                      <a className="dropdown-item" href="product.html">
                        Juices
                      </a>
                      <a className="dropdown-item" href="product.html">
                        Almond Milks
                      </a>
                      <a className="dropdown-item" href="product.html">
                        Protien Milkshake
                      </a>
                      <a className="dropdown-item" href="product.html">
                        Cleanses
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </li> */}
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <NavLink
                      className="nav-link"
                      to="/product-listing"
                      data-toggle="modal"
                      data-target="#loginModal"
                    >
                      Shop
                    </NavLink>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a
                      className="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                      href="#"
                      id="navbarDropdown"
                      role="button"
                      data-toggle="dropdown"
                      aria-haspopup="true"
                      aria-expanded="false"
                    >
                      Learn
                    </a>
                    <div
                      className="dropdown-menu"
                      aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown"
                    >
                      <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
                        Process
                      </a>
                      <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
                        About Us
                      </a>
                      <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
                        Blog
                      </a>
                      <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
                        News
                      </a>
                      <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
                        Beyond The Bottle
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <a
                      className="nav-link"
                      href="#"
                      data-toggle="modal"
                      data-target="#loginModal"
                    >
                      Login
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <a
                      className="nav-link"
                      href="#"
                      data-toggle="modal"
                      data-target="#signupModal"
                    >
                      Sign Up
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <form className="dvSearch my-2 my-lg-0 px-3 position-relative">
                  <input
                    className={`form-control mr-sm-2 ${border}`}
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Search"
                    aria-label="Search"
                  />
                  <button
                    className="btn my-2 my-sm-0 position-absolute"
                    type="submit"
                  >
                    <i className={`fa fa-search ${textColor}`}></i>
                  </button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </header>
      ) : (
        <PageNotFound />
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

EXPORT DEFAULT HEADER.JS---

```
export default Header;
```

Comment: I gave this answer in quora. I recommend u making navbar a component and returning nav through it.

Comment: Hi Lalan Kumar thank you for your time but quora deleted my question before i see your answer due to violation. Can you please share your answer here would be a great help for me.